# How do I compare a time value to all the time values in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I want to apply a condition to a column in a dataframe. The column has time values in the format `HH:MM:SS` and I want to compare it to a fixed time value(threshold), but I am getting errors. Converting the threshold value to `datetime.datetime.strptime` gives me error. What I want to ask is - In order to compare any two time values how do I store them or what do I convert them into so that they can be compared? The threshold value is in string and the column values are in `datetime.time` format.

When I do this-

```
threshold = datetime.datetime.strptime('1:04:00','%H:%M:%S').time()  
df_styled = df.style.apply(lambda x:['background:red' if x > threshold else "background:white" for x in df['Total Time']], axis=0)
```

I get -

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

When I do this-

```
threshold = datetime.datetime.strptime('1:04:00','%H:%M:%S')
df['Total Time'] = df['Total Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%H:%M:%S'))
df_styled = df.style.apply(lambda x:['background:red' if x > threshold else 'background:white' for x in df['Total Time']], axis=0)
```

I get the error

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare timedeltas created by [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
threshold = pd.Timedelta('1:04:00')
df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Time'].astype(str))

df_styled = df.style.apply(lambda x:['background:red' if x > threshold else "background:white" for x in df['Total Time']], axis=0)
```

EDIT: Solution for your problematic data:

```
df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['Total Time'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: This gives me - ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed

Comment: @Pete - Is possible investigate whcih value return error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 264, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.array_to_timedelta64
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 315, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.parse_timedelta_string
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/conditionalformat.py", line 27, in <module>
    df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Time'].astype(str))

Comment: @Pete - I ask not for full error, but which value caused it. It is more detective investigate work 0 test if failed first 10 rows? then first 20 rows?... until find problematic value

Comment: @Pete - hmmm, thinking - are format in `df['Total Time']` like `10:00:23` ? `HH:MM:SS` ?

Comment: You mean there is a value in the column which is giving this error?

Comment: @Pete - yop, I guess one or more. (or all)

Comment: I tried applying to the first 5 or even first 3 rows. It throws me the same error. Would values like 0:00:00 be a problem? There are no negative or missing values in the column.

Comment: @Pete - What is `print (df['Total Time'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: [datetime.time(6, 8, 7), datetime.time(0, 44, 41), datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 46, 38), datetime.time(0, 28, 35)] @jezrael

Comment: @Pete - Tested and for me working well, what is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 1.2.4 @jezrael

Comment: @Pete - For you working well EDIT in my answer?

Comment: No I am still getting the same error. Are you saying that I should create a seperate dataframe for that column?

Comment: @Pete - If your solution not working for first 3 values in `df['Total Time']` then failed also  if run `EDIT` part. It is only for testing if works or not.

Comment: The edit code is working! But when I use the column it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pete - How you test `I tried applying to the first 5 or even first 3 rows.` ?

Comment: I actually did this `df_styled = df.head(3).style.apply(lambda x:['background:red' if x > threshold else "background:white" for x in df['Total Time']], axis=0)`

Comment: @Pete - OK, so you try convert all column to timede;tas and the filter first 3 rows? You need `df = df.head(3)` before my solution, before `df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Time'].astype(str))`

Comment: thanks I understand now that the conversion is the problem. So I am trying to increment the no of rows by 10 and checking it.

Comment: So the table has 65 rows and I did `df[' Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df[' Total Time'].head(64).astype(str))` and it works. Only when I change it to 65 the error comes.

Comment: @Pete - So what is `print (df['Total Time'].head(65).tail(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: [datetime.time(0, 22, 32), datetime.time(0, 0, 10), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 5, 47)] @jezrael

Comment: @Pete - Problem is `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 5, 47)`

Comment: @Pete - Solution - `df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['Total Time'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: Hmm yes since all the data is in an excel file and without clicking on the cell its format looked like HH:MM:SS I got confused. Thank you so much for helping me out!